# The getter was called on null error when using Provider on Flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I have provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class AppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Box tjkBox;

  // Language
  String _ln = "ru";
  String get ln => _ln;
  set ln(String l) {
    _ln = l;
    tjkBox.put("language", l);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  AppProvider() {
    tjkBox = Hive.box("tjk");
    _ln = tjkBox.get("language", defaultValue: "ru");
    print("ln = $_ln");
  }
}
```

I wrap my root widget:

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<AppProvider>(create: (_) => AppProvider()),
    // here goes other providers
  ],
  child:  ...
  
);
```

Then I am trying to access to the ln property like this:

```
Consumer<AppProvider>(
  builder: (context, app, child) => Text(app?.ln),
)
```

Or like this:

```
Text(Provider.of<AppProvider>(context).ln)
```

But it keeps giving me error:
`The getter 'ln' was called on null.`

Please explain, What I am missing?

Comment: Where you create your provider class instance?

Comment: @fartem I think I don't create. Where and how to create?

Answer (score 0):

Provider concepts and samples available on [Provider docs](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Wrap root of your `Consumer` widget (app widget or a root screen) with `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => AppProvider(),
  child: ...
)
```

And in all child widgets you can access `AppProvider` model.

Comment: Are widget that called Provider model is in root of model scope?

Comment: Yes. If I try to print ln after button tap, it works

Comment: Where are you calling Provider access?

Comment: I use it as title of my AppBar

Comment: And `AppBar` initialized in widget that child of `MultiProvider`?

Comment: My MultiProvider in my main.dart, AppBar in HomeV.dart which is routed in main.dart

Comment: Are you created `AppBar` in `build` method  of State/Widget in `homeV.dart`?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way I can provide you full source code?